Android baseline-profile setup getting INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE error
When setting up the baseline-profile module via Android Studio I am running into the following error:
Exception thrown during onBeforeAll invocation of plugin AndroidTestApkInstallerPlugin: ErrorName: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE
NameSpace: DdmlibAndroidDeviceController
ErrorCode: 1
ErrorType: TEST
Message: Failed to install split APK(s): [/Users/james.cullimore/Desktop/someApp/baseline-profile/build/outputs/apk/nonMinifiedRelease/baseline-profile-nonMinifiedRelease.apk]
Failed to install split APK(s): [/Users/james.cullimore/Desktop/someApp/baseline-profile/build/outputs/apk/nonMinifiedRelease/baseline-profile-nonMinifiedRelease.apk]
Failed to commit install session 167650299 with command package install-commit 167650299. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE: Downgrade detected: Update version code 0 is older than current 273
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to commit install session 167650299 with command package install-commit 167650299. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE: Downgrade detected: Update version code 0 is older than current 10
    at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstallerBase.installCommit(SplitApkInstallerBase.java:154)
    at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:85)
    at com.android.ddmlib.IDeviceSharedImpl.installPackages(IDeviceSharedImpl.java:395)
    at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.lambda$installPackages$36(DeviceImpl.java:1492)
    at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.logRun3(DeviceImpl.java:1834)
    at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installPackages(DeviceImpl.java:1489)
    at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.lambda$installPackages$37(DeviceImpl.java:1504)
    at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.logRun3(DeviceImpl.java:1834)
    at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installPackages(DeviceImpl.java:1500)
    at com.android.tools.utp.plugins.deviceprovider.ddmlib.DdmlibAndroidDevice.installPackages(DdmlibAndroidDevice.kt:74)
    at com.android.tools.utp.plugins.deviceprovider.ddmlib.DdmlibAndroidDeviceController$executeAsync$deferred$1.invokeSuspend(DdmlibAndroidDeviceController.kt:254)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:749)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)

I tried setting the versionCode manually and uninstalling the app, but to no prevail

When selecting the Baseline Profile Generator make sure to use a different package name than what the app uses. For example:
:app -> com.example
:baslineprofile -> com.example.baselineprofile

When using the same package, this causes the above issue.
